# Preparing exposed windowsill board for painting

Tags: paint, sanding, window-frame

For a newbie DIYer, any guidance on preparing this windowsill for painting? The board is exposed and fibers[image] are standing out. So a bit unsure what is the best way to sand it. Do i put a seal of any sorts on top?

Comment: Ugh, that looks like MDF.  It also looks like it got wet, and does what wet MDF does: expand.  Have you solved the source of the wetness yet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That wood looks to be MDF.  Which is a poor choice of product for a window sill.

It appears the wood has absorbed moisture and some areas are bulged. The wood itself is crumbling on the surface.

I would replace it with a pre-primed pine product of the same or close to same dimensions. Even better would be a [PVC product.](https://www.vintagewoodworks.com/pptrimbds.html)

If replacement is outside your comfort zone and you still want to go with paint, here are some suggestions.

Sand lightly with a 320 or 400 grit paper. Rougher grains will destroy the surface.

I would then skim the surface with a joint compound. When dry sand lightly again with 600 grit.

Prime and paint.